# Is it possible to create a MingW / MSYS based Windows toolchain to compile Glibc dependent applications for Linux?

Tags: windows, mingw, cross-compiling, glibc

I was following instructions [here](http://gnutoolchains.com/building/) and [here](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/) to build a toolchain which would work on Windows and compile applications for Linux and different hardware platforms. At first I tried to create cross-compiler for i686-linux to test it on a generic Debian 8 system.

Binutils and GCC compiled fine, but I got stuck at Glibc. It told me:

```
*** The GNU C library is currently not available for this platform.
```

I see that Sysprogs toolchains are using Newlib instead of Glibc but I haven't found any explanations except that Newlib is a good choice for embedded devices.

Does it mean that Newlib is actually the only choice for Windows -> Linux and that there is no way to compile software which depends on Glibc? Maybe there are "cheats", like copying pre-built Glibc from the target platform or some other workaround?

In theory, I don't even need Glibc built on Windows, I need just some "Glibc compatible stub" built for the target architecture to link (only dynamically, of course) against while compiling for the target platform and OS. Or am I totally wrong here and GCC cannot link to a different C library than GCC itself was linked to?

Or should I forget it and accept the fact that it is impossible (and, most probably, never will be possible) to achieve full Glibc and Linux kernel compatible C/C++ cross-compiling from Windows to GNU/Linux?

I will accept the answer which explains how GCC and Glibc are related and whether it is possible or not to link against Glibc different from C library used when GCC itself was built, and provide some insight about why it is / is not possible.

Comment: For goodness sake, WHY would you want this

Comment: Mostly because I and my colleagues are accustomed to Visual Studio which has good code editors and great debugger (and recently added support for remote GDB debugging). It would take too much time to learn developing on Linux for entire team. Of course, final builds can be done on the target machine itself and we'll need experienced Linux developer anyway, but for the entire team it is more convenient to use familiar development tools.

Comment: I have years of experience with Windows and C. This is an awful idea, what you are asking. The ONLY reason you should dare put Windows anywhere in the development chain is if you are developing FOR Windows. Please, for all that is good, save yourself the headache and dont do this. Build Linux tools WITH Linux

Answer (score 3):

my guess is you're using `--target` when building glibc when you really need to use `--host` (which is different from how newlib is configured -- best to not ask why).

that said, the glibc build system requires a case-sensitive file system as it creates files like `foo.oS` and `foo.os` which are very different things.  on a system like Windows, that means the build will be corrupted and fail since `foo.oS` and `foo.os` refer to the same file.  there are patches out there to hack around this, but really you'd be better off booting a VM and doing the toolchain build inside of that.

NB: i'm not saying you need the VM to do all your development.  you just need the VM to build the cross-compiler which you'd then run under Windows.  this would be a [canadian cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#Canadian_Cross) build.

rather than do all this yourself by hand, please check out [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/).  it handles/patches/fixes a lot of common errors people make when trying to create cross-compilers.